# Unable to install java on windows 10

Tags: java, windows, installation

Fresh installation of Windows 10 Home Build 10586.
Trying to install java, file jdk-8u101-windows-x64.exe.
After running the installer, as administrator, in the task manager appears for 2 seconds "Java Platform SE binary" and then it disappears with no error window appearing. 
Xamarin installer tried to install jdk-7u79-windows-i586.exe but was also unable returning "JDK installation exited with error code: 123".

I boot also in safe mode and tried with no luck.

Any ideas of what is happening?

Comment: Did you tried to download it again?

Comment: Maybe you should use [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/tour) instead of Stack Overflow to ask this to avoid getting downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

User account name had special characters (greek) and this caused the problem.
Creating a new user account with english characters solved the problem.

Comment: sounds interesting issue, You should file a bug in jdk http://bugreport.java.com/submit_intro.do,

Comment: Thanks for reporting this incident, we are working on this to fix this issue - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8162683

Answer (score 0):

If you jdk install is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2`:

`SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2`

`SET Path=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin;`